# SQLCODE=-1042ect: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred. SQLSTATE=58004

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect to the Db2 database on Cloud using Python.

```
dsn_hostname = ".." 
dsn_uid = ".."       
dsn_pwd = ".."      

dsn_driver = "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}"
dsn_database = ".."            
dsn_port = ".."                 
dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"            
dsn_security = "SSL"



   dsn = (
    "DRIVER={0};"
    "DATABASE={1};"
    "HOSTNAME={2};"
    "PORT={3};"
    "PROTOCOL={4};"
    "UID={5};"
    "PWD={6};"
    "SECURITY={7};").format(dsn_driver, dsn_database, dsn_hostname, dsn_port, dsn_protocol, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd,dsn_security)

try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
    print ("Connected to database: ", dsn_database, "as user: ", dsn_uid, "on host: ", dsn_hostname)

except:
    print ("Unable to connect: ", ibm_db.conn_errormsg() )
```

But,I am getting this error-:

SQLCODE=-1042ect:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
SQLSTATE=58004

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Microsoft Windows with python and clidriver then you may be affected by a defect in IBM's clidriver (which gets installed by default when you install the python ibm_db module).  This problem only affects some workstations, not all, it depends on what is already installed and what is already on the PATH.

clidriver supplies a copy of the VC12 runtime DLL files, but clidriver can fail to load the required DLL files at runtime and gives an unhelpful error message that does not mention the real cause of the problem.

There is a workaround, described below, which puts the required DLL files on the PATH.

Use `pip show ibm_db` to find the "Location:" of your site-packages directory for python. Suppose for example, that "Location:" is `c:\python\lib\site-packages`

Your site-packages directory will be in a different place, but try to understand the idea.

Modify your PATH environment variable value to append the following directory (for example):

> c:\python\lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT

In other words , add **your** site-packages path with suffix `\clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT`

After modifying the PATH, close the command-promt/shell window, and reopen it. Retry the python ibm_db database connection. This normally cures the SQL1042C symptom.

If you do not have permission to modify the PATH environment variable value, you can also copy the contents of that `amd64.VC12.CRT` directory (only two files both DLL) , into another directory that is already on the PATH when python runs.

If you are encrypting your database connections with SSL/TLS, you sometimes (but not always, it depends on the clidriver version) also need to add a second directory to the PATH ( ... `site-packages\clidriver\bin\icc64` ) .

Comment: many thanks, very clear and helpful

Answer (score 0):

**check your ibmdb connection parameters**

```
conn=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=dbname;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=32286;SECURITY=SSL;SSLSererCertificate=DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt;UID=username;PWD=passwd",'','')
```

conn=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=**dbname**;HOSTNAME=**hostname**;PORT=32286;SECURITY=SSL;SSLSererCertificate=**DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt**;UID=**username**;PWD=**passwd**",'','')

**Ensure that ssl certificate parameter --***filename with extension*****
SSLSererCertificate=**DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt**