# Connection Error while connecting to Jupyter notebook using DB2 database

Tags: python, sql, r

When I try to connect my Jupyter notebook to the IBM Db2 database. It gives me this error. Please help me to fix it. I've tried everything but, couldn't find any solution.

```
SQLCODE=-1042ect:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred. SQLSTATE=58004.
```

Comment: Please check if this is a duplicate to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68857222/sqlcode-1042ect-ibmcli-driver-sql1042c-an-unexpected-system-error-occurred]. If you still need help, please provide some more information like OS, code lines you are using, etc.

Comment: I still could not found any solution. I am using IBM cloud and there I have created a free db2 database which I want to connect with my jupyter notebook through credentials.